# Changing font in Sublime Text 3

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3

I want to change the font in Sublime Text 3 to Roboto Mono, so I downloaded the file and installed it on my computer (macOS).
Then I go and open Sublime Text 3, go to "Settings --> Preferences", getting to the split screen where I put into the right side this:

```
"font_face": "Roboto Mono",
"font_size": 10,
```

Now this is supposed to work but it doesn't.

Can someone advise please?

---

Update: 
The error I'm getting is:

```
Unable to save ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: got it now, it's under user settings which are here: 
"Preferences --> Package Settings --> Advanced new file --> User settings"
Saving it here finally works

Comment: I couldn't get a new font to show until I restarted Sublime. It's possible it's because Sublime was open while I installed the font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201749) support article from Apple for installing fonts and check if you have installed it properly.

If you did, check the name of installed fonts.

Then, go to `Settings -> Preferences` and on the right hand side(*User settings*) place:

```
{
    "font_face": "Roboto Mono",
    "font_size": 10
}
```

Comment: thx Dinko, that's what I'm doing actually. The error seems to be from within Sublime then?

Answer (score 3):

try changing font size (to 15 for instance) using this:

```
"font_size": 15
```

updated my font in my case.